# Where to put DLL file?

Tags: java, deployment, dll

I am calling C++ method using DLL file in my Java project. Right now, I have hard coded the path.

The application will be deployed on many machines and it also run on multiple machine. Where should I put my DLL file so that I can load it and call it on any machine?

Comment: BTW - there is no place on a Mac or *nix machine where you can put a DLL and load it.  Do you have natives for those platforms?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen applications that put the DLL into the JAR file. At run-time, they extract the DLL from the JAR into a temporary directory and then access it there.

It's not the most efficient approach but the easiest from a deployment perspective.

Comment: *"It's not the most efficient approach but the easiest"*  Deploying natives using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your DLL is in the classpath.

One such way to do so is to put the path to the DLL in PATH environment variable.

Other option is to add it to the VM arguments in the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/my/dll -cp /my/classpath/goes/here MainClass
```

If you are developing a complex application, that has to be stable you have to ensure that the DLL you need is put somewhere, where the OS is going to look for it, probably think of an installer script/program.

Answer (score 0):

C:\WINDOWS\system32 (assuming C is the drive where windows is installed, probably you can get it from registry)

I used to use windows long time ago & not an expert, so I made a google search for you and find the link http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/dll.htm

See the last topic in the link (the one starting with headline **Using Regsvr32.exe to Register DLLs**)

Comment: regsrv32 will only register COM/ActiveX .dll's, and only if they have a DllRegisterServer() entry.  Probably not the case here.